# Firebase (Unknown Source) .onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can get the firebase data.But I got this error when I try to get user data.I cheked the user rules and it's all looks ok.What is the issue ? Actually it's work on `AppCompatActivity` but it's not work when I switch to `Fragment`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Members": {
      ".indexOn": ["Doka", "limit"]
    },
      "kelessmothlar": {
      ".indexOn": ["smothkelesonucu"]
    },
      "Dokas": {
      ".indexOn": ["Doka", "limit"]
    },
      ".read": true,
".write": true
  }
}
```

Error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.samin.world.BlankFragment2$1.onDataChange(BlankFragment2.java:723)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
```

723 line is

```
if (!dataSnapshot.child("Members")
    .child(user.getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .child("smothy5")
    .getValue().toString()
    .equals(dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("Games").getValue())) {
```

Code java

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {



private FirebaseAuth user;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();



String limit;
String limitsmoth2;
String limitsmoth3;
String limitsmoth4;
String limitsmoth5;




int counter1 = 0;
int countersmoth2 = 0;
int countersmoth3 = 0;
int countersmoth4 = 0;
int countersmoth5 = 0;
int counter6 = 0;
int counter7 = 0;
int counter8 = 0;
int counter9 = 0;
int counter10 = 0;
int counter11 = 0;
int counter12 = 0;
int counter13 = 0;
int counter14 = 0;
int counter15 = 0;


String old;
String oldsmoth2;
String oldsmoth3;
String oldsmoth4;
String oldsmoth5;
String old6;
String old7;
String old8;
String old9;
String old10;
String old11;
String old12;
String old13;
String old14;
String old15;


String deep;
String deepsmoth2;
String deepsmoth3;
String deepsmoth4;
String deepsmoth5;
String deep6;
String deep7;
String deep8;
String deep9;
String deep10;
String deep11;
String deep12;
String deep13;
String deep14;
String deep15;




public BlankFragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);



    final RelativeLayout smoth1 = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1);


    final LinearLayout smoth1liner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1liner);
    final LinearLayout smoth1liner2 = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1liner2);
    final LinearLayout smoth1kose = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1kose);
    final LinearLayout smoth1kilit = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1kilit);
    final LinearLayout smoth1free = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1free);
    final LinearLayout smoth1oldliner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1oldlinear);
    final ImageView smoth1cal = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1cal);
    final ImageView smoth1simage = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy1simage);



    final RelativeLayout smoth2 = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2);


    final LinearLayout smoth2liner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2liner);
    final LinearLayout smoth2liner2 = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2liner2);
    final LinearLayout smoth2kose = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2kose);
    final LinearLayout smoth2kilit = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2kilit);
    final LinearLayout smoth2free = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2free);
    final LinearLayout smoth2oldliner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2oldlinear);
    final ImageView smoth2cal = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2cal);
    final ImageView smoth2simage = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy2simage);


    final RelativeLayout smoth3 = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3);


    final LinearLayout smoth3liner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3liner);
    final LinearLayout smoth3liner2 = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3liner2);
    final LinearLayout smoth3kose = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3kose);
    final LinearLayout smoth3kilit = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3kilit);
    final LinearLayout smoth3free = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3free);
    final LinearLayout smoth3oldliner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3oldlinear);
    final ImageView smoth3cal = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3cal);
    final ImageView smoth3simage = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy3simage);



    final RelativeLayout smoth4 = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4);


    final LinearLayout smoth4liner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4liner);
    final LinearLayout smoth4liner2 = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4liner2);
    final LinearLayout smoth4kose = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4kose);
    final LinearLayout smoth4kilit = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4kilit);
    final LinearLayout smoth4free = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4free);
    final LinearLayout smoth4oldliner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4oldlinear);
    final ImageView smoth4cal = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4cal);
    final ImageView smoth4simage = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy4simage);



    final RelativeLayout smoth5 = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5);


    final LinearLayout smoth5liner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5liner);
    final LinearLayout smoth5liner2 = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5liner2);
    final LinearLayout smoth5kose = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5kose);
    final LinearLayout smoth5kilit = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5kilit);
    final LinearLayout smoth5free = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5free);
    final LinearLayout smoth5oldliner = (LinearLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5oldlinear);
    final ImageView smoth5cal = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5cal);
    final ImageView smoth5simage = (ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.smothy5simage);




    final TextView smoth1text = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy1text);
    final TextView smoth2text = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy2text);
    final TextView smoth3text = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy3text);
    final TextView smoth4text = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy4text);
    final TextView smoth5text = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy5text);



    final TextView smoth1deep = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy1deep);
    final TextView smoth2deep = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy2deep);
    final TextView smoth3deep = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy3deep);
    final TextView smoth4deep = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy4deep);
    final TextView smoth5deep = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy5deep);


    final TextView smoth1time = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy1time);
    final TextView smoth2time = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy2time);
    final TextView smoth3time = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy3time);
    final TextView smoth4time = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy4time);
    final TextView smoth5time = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy5time);



    final TextView smoth1old = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy1old);
    final TextView smoth2old = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy2old);
    final TextView smoth3old = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy3old);
    final TextView smoth4old = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy4old);
    final TextView smoth5old = myview.findViewById(com.samin.world.R.id.smothy5old);


    try {
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        String langs = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

                        String Gamessmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("Games").getValue().toString();
                        String timesmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("Newtime").getValue().toString();


                        if (langs.equals("tr")) {
                            oldsmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("Prediction").getValue().toString();

                        } else {

                            oldsmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("old").getValue().toString();

                        }

                        deepsmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("deep").getValue().toString();
                        limitsmoth4 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("limit").getValue().toString();
                        if (Gamessmoth4.equals(" ")) {
                            //Yazilar
                            smoth4text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4deep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4old.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4text.setText(Gamessmoth4);
                            smoth4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //Linerlar
                            smoth4liner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4liner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4kose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4kilit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4free.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4oldliner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //Imageler
                            smoth4cal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth4simage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } else {

                            //Yazilar
                            smoth4text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4deep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            smoth4time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4old.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //Linerlar
                            smoth4liner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4liner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4kose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4kilit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4free.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4oldliner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //Imageler
                            smoth4cal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth4simage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            if (!dataSnapshot.child("Members").child(user.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("smothy4").getValue().toString().equals(dataSnapshot.child("smothy4").child("Games").getValue())) {
                                if (countersmoth4 == 0) {
                                    smoth4old.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.credit) + " " + limitsmoth4);
                                    countersmoth4++;
                                }
                                //patopat1.setText(peli1);
                                smoth4time.setText(timesmoth4);
                                if (countersmoth4 == 1) {
                                    //smoth4deep.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.show));
                                    smoth4deep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    countersmoth4++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                //patopat1.setText(peli1);
                                smoth4time.setText(timesmoth4);
                                smoth4old.setText(oldsmoth4);
                                smoth4deep.setText(deepsmoth4);
                                smoth4deep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                smoth4free.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Log.d("ERR", "BURASI ÇALIŞTI");
                            }


                        }

                        String Gamessmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("Games").getValue().toString();
                        String timesmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("Newtime").getValue().toString();


                        if (langs.equals("tr")) {
                            oldsmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("Prediction").getValue().toString();

                        } else {

                            oldsmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("old").getValue().toString();

                        }


                        deepsmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("deep").getValue().toString();
                        limitsmoth5 = dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("limit").getValue().toString();
                        if (Gamessmoth5.equals(" ")) {
                            //Yazilar
                            smoth5text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5deep.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5old.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5text.setText(Gamessmoth5);
                            smoth5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //Linerlar
                            smoth5liner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5liner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5kose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5kilit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5free.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5oldliner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //Imageler
                            smoth5cal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            smoth5simage.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                        } else {

                            //Yazilar
                            smoth5text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5deep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            smoth5time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5old.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //Linerlar
                            smoth5liner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5liner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5kose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5kilit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5free.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5oldliner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //Imageler
                            smoth5cal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            smoth5simage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            if (!dataSnapshot.child("Members").child(user.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("smothy5").getValue().toString().equals(dataSnapshot.child("smothy5").child("Games").getValue())) {
                                if (countersmoth5 == 0) {
                                    smoth5old.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.credit) + " " + limitsmoth5);
                                    countersmoth5++;
                                }
                                //patopat1.setText(peli1);
                                smoth5time.setText(timesmoth5);
                                if (countersmoth5 == 1) {
                                    //smoth5deep.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.show));
                                    smoth5deep.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    countersmoth5++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                //patopat1.setText(peli1);
                                smoth5time.setText(timesmoth5);
                                smoth5old.setText(oldsmoth5);
                                smoth5deep.setText(deepsmoth5);
                                smoth5deep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                smoth5free.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Log.d("ERR", "BURASI ÇALIŞTI");
                            }


                        }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), R.string.errenoughtcredit, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    return myview;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Dorbagna. Is that the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem? Reducing scope highly increases the chances that someone here can help. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ♡

Comment: I'm sorry.It's my bad,but body limit wasn't enogh.

Comment: All we can say at this point is that one of the expressions on line 723 has a `null` and you're trying to call a function or property on it. If you can't reduce the code to a minimal amount and still get the problem, the best advice is to thoroughly study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what i have seen in your code is that

> user is null

**See**

Try this

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

**instead**

```
private FirebaseAuth user;
```

**then use this on line 723**

```
 if (!dataSnapshot.child("Kullanıcılar").child(user.getUid()).child("maç5").getValue().toString().equals(dataSnapshot.child("maç5").child("Oynayanlar").getValue())) {
```

Hope it will work